# Rails - How to stop Rack Rewrite gem persisting between projects?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rack, rack-rewrite

I'm using the excellent [Rack Rewrite gem](https://github.com/jtrupiano/rack-rewrite) in one of my Rails projects.

I used it to rewrite http requests to https://whatever.tld. 
Here's the snippet from config/application.rb:

```
   config.middleware.insert_before(Rack::Lock, Rack::Rewrite) do
      r301 %r{.*}, 'https://whatever.tld$&', :scheme => 'http'
    end
```

...which works nicely.

However, now every time I boot up ANY rails app in dev, it kicks me off to https://whatever.tld

Does anyone know how to tell the middleware not to use that rule any more?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where are you adding the code? It shouldn't persist across projects.

Comment: I know. Browser cache. D'oh :o)

Answer (score 3):

I assume you're accessing the other projects via the same URL (like http://localhost:3000)?

You're using a 301 permanent redirect here, which means the browser won't even check with the server before redirecting for subsequent visits. So if http://localhost:3000/ returns a 301, it doesn't matter what server is running, it won't be accessed.

Use a different URL that is unique to your redirect app, or a temporary redirect. Or clear out your browser cache between switching projects.

Comment: 'Clear the browser cache' - totally worked (and how stupid do I feel now?)

Thank you Daniel!

Comment: We all have those moments :D